# Change Logout Url

Tags: logout, ee4

I have **EE 4.0.9** , when members logout from their accounts , the logout path redirect them to home page automatically ,how can i change the redirect link when members logout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try after updating the `CP session type` to `Session ID only`. You can change it from `Settings >> Security & Privacy`.